# Excel - Finding All Numbers and Putting in a single column

Tags: excel

I’m given a bunch of numbers in a single column however there is a lot of data inbetween each. Is there a way to extract all of the numbers into a single column, where each number is directly below another in the column?

Comment: Yes, there is!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that you can adapt to your needs.

With data in column **A** that is a mixture of numbers, text values, and empties, in **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(ISNUMBER(A:A)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

As you see, the formula basically filters out all text values.

Answer (score 0):

With vba:
Paste this in standard module and run

```
Sub ListNumbers()

    Dim mix As Range, num As Range, c As Range, lst As Range, i As Integer

    Set mix = Application.InputBox("Select a mixed range", "Mixed", Range(Cells(1), Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp)).Address, Type:=8)
    Set res = Application.InputBox("Select first cell for result", "Result", Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Address, Type:=8)

    For Each c In mix
        If IsNumeric(c) = True Then
            res.Offset(i).Value = c.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c

    If MsgBox("Do you wan´t to sort the result", vbYesNo, "Sort") = vbYes Then
        Set lst = res.Resize(i)
        lst.Sort key1:=lst, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If

End Sub
```